# How to create buffer zones around points and linestrings but not around polygons & multipolygons using ogr2ogr?

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr

I create a sample `test.geojson` file using Python:

```
import shapely.wkt
import geopandas as gpd

geoms=[
    shapely.wkt.loads("POLYGON((0 0, 0 1, 1 1, 1 0, 0 0))"),
    shapely.wkt.loads("POLYGON((2 2, 2 3, 3 4, 3 2, 2 2))"),
    shapely.wkt.loads("MULTIPOLYGON(((-2 -2, -2 -3, -3 -4, -3 -2, -2 -2)),((-1.5 -1.5, -1 -1.5, -1 -2,-1.5 -1.5)))"),
    shapely.wkt.loads("LINESTRING(0 4, 1 2)"),
    shapely.wkt.loads("POINT(5 5)"),
    shapely.wkt.loads("POINT(-1 -1)")
]

s = gpd.GeoSeries(geoms).set_crs(3006)
df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(dict(geometry=s,attr0=['A','B','C','D','E','F']))

df.to_file("test.geojson")
```

Visualization of the geometries there: `df.plot()`

[image]

I would like to use  create `test_buffered.geojson`from `test.geojson` using [`ogr2ogr`](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html). I aim to leave `Polygon`s and `Multipolygon`s unchanged, but create a 1m buffer zone around points and linestrings.

**How can I create buffer zones around `Point`s and `Linestring`s (but not `Polygon`s & `Multipolygon`s) using [`ogr2ogr`](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html)?**

To achieve the same result using Python, I can do:

```
import geopandas as gpd

df = gpd.read_file("test.geojson")
df = df.assign(original_geometry_type = df.geometry.geom_type)

def conditional_buffer(original_geometry_type,geometry):
    if not (original_geometry_type=='Polygon' or original_geometry_type=='MultiPolygon'):
        return geometry.buffer(1)
    else:
        return geometry

df = df.assign(geometry = df.apply(lambda row:
                                   conditional_buffer(
                                       row['original_geometry_type'],
                                       row['geometry']
                                   ),axis=1))
df.to_file("test_buffered.geojson")
```

Result: `df.plot()`

[image]

as expected. I would like to use `ogr2ogr` to achieve the same thing.

Comment: You might use -sql option in the ogr2ogr command.

Comment: That is the way to do it. @FardinEsmaeili Do you want to write a full command as an answer? If you want, I won't do it myself.

Comment: Thank you. I made the example a bit more general to better suit real world use case.

Comment: Oh wait, my Python example is wrong. Correcting it...

Comment: I think it's ok now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON buffered.json -dialect sqlite -sql "select st_buffer(geometry,1) from buffertest where st_geometrytype(geometry) not in ('POLYGON','MULTIPOLYGON') UNION select geometry from buffertest where st_geometrytype(geometry) in ('POLYGON','MULTIPOLYGON')" buffertest.json
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Nice! I think this way the end file won't have the `attr0` column, though that column does make it to the end result in Python. I'm trying to come up with an edit suggestion to fix that...

Comment: This: `ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON test_buffered.geojson -dialect sqlite -sql "select st_buffer(geometry,1) as geometry, attr0 from test where st_geometrytype(geometry) not in ('POLYGON','MULTIPOLYGON') UNION select geometry, attr0 from test where st_geometrytype(geometry) in ('POLYGON','MULTIPOLYGON')" test.geojson
` does fix it, but does not if I don't know the column names in advance (like in real world scenario).

Comment: If want to keep all columns, this will do it I think: `ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON test_buffered.geojson -dialect sqlite -sql "select st_buffer(geometry,1) as geometry, * from test where st_geometrytype(geometry) not in ('POLYGON','MULTIPOLYGON') UNION select geometry, * from test where st_geometrytype(geometry) in ('POLYGON','MULTIPOLYGON')" test.geojson`.

Comment: Notice that `select st_buffer(geometry,1) as geometry, *` works here as you wish by chance. The query returns two geometries but because GeoJSON supports only one geometry then just the first one is stored. If you output into PostGIS you would get two geometry columns.

Comment: Oh ok, that sounds bad. Is there a way to force it to choose the buffered geometry? I guess there is not guarantee GeoJSON will always choose the buffered one.

Comment: I suppose that the first geometry is taken and all the following ones are skipped but I can't say if it is guaranteed. The source code is in https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/tree/master/ogr/ogrsf_frmts/geojson. Maybe you could do a test with various data sources and for example st_centroid. All geometries in the GeoJSON should be points then.

Comment: I asked about this here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/447351/191643.